# Can related queries be executed in a single plan?

Tags: postgresql, performance, execution-plan

I'm experimenting with a web app. It executes the exact same set of **closely related** queries each time to update the fields on the page. There are about 25 of them, and many share subqueries. Intermediate results are often the same for different queries. The database is read-only.

Is it possible to combine these queries to improve performance? The queries are already communicated and executed in parallel. It's the duplicate intermediate results that I would like to eliminate.

The output of the queries don't follow a uniform format: there are different columns each time. One query might return a single count, a second query a few rows with a few columns... So using UNION is not an option.

Comment: How are the queries related? Are they all to fill in different fields of the web page or do you use the results from one to feed into another query (ie a front end join or the N+1 problem)

Comment: Sounds like an X-Y Problem™. Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: I rephrased the question to include more context and focus more on the core problem, less on the solution I had in mind.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that the "repeated subqueries" really are a problem? Most likely the data they return is cached after the first query, so subsequent queries will get them from the cache. If you really have proof that this is a bottleneck, you could store the results in a temp table and use the temp tables instead of the sub-queries. But as writing is substantially slower than reading, your subqueries must contribute to a substantial part of the runtime for this approach to make a difference.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the forum! Could you please go to dbfiddle.uk and construct a/some sample table(s) & some sample query(ies) so that we can see what you mean?

Comment: Please show a few of those similar queries.